# Is there a way to open .html from VSCode terminal/debug console link in browser?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Right now it seems that the terminal in Visual Studio Code provides a way to `Ctrl+Click` and open files from the terminal/debug console in a new editor (for a file in the system):

Yet, in this particular case, I'd like to open a `.html` file in the browser and not in the editor. Is there any way to configure this (or maybe even do this through some extension)?

Use case: I'd like to see the html created as an output of a test run in the browser and not inside a Visual Studio Code editor:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried configuring your OS to open HTML files with your browser of choice?

Comment: I don't see how that's related... the VSCode action doesn't make it to the system (it directly opens it inside of VSCode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really supported by VSCode itself.

I created a ticket for that in:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108853

Where it's explained that it's not supported and won't be implemented in the foreseeable future, but who knows, maybe in a few years from now it may make the cut ;)